# Django Angular Social Medial authentication

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on app where user can log-in using your Facebook or any social media account in angular side.

I am comfortable with the django framework and AngularJS.

But in my application user can only login r signing with social media account.
so how do I manage authentication mechanism with facebook.

I am expecting some direction so that I can go forward with the app.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question but I'm assuming your are using django rest framework.

Best way for social authentication is [django-rest-auth](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This has nothing to do with Angular or any other client side code. the client will just feed on to the REST authentication API.

Comment: I am new in Django, I am confused in how to authenticate user.because when I login using Facebook or google in angular side I am getting email id.Now using this email and some user details I want to register user in database using Django.and next time when same user sign in using same email id he can access his account..please help me.

Comment: Please read the documents on rest auth. It'll not be difficult to figure out if you know DRF.

Comment: ok, { "provider": "Facebook",  "code": "" } what is 'code' in this request?